# Configuring Memory Protection Unit on Atmel SAMD51

Tags: arm, cortex-m

I am trying to configure the MPU of SAMD51 (Cortex-M4) to protect one 1k of FLASH from any access, and 1k of SRAM from write access that would contains sensitive information that should never be access or corrupted (from a SW bug or any other way).

I wish to protect those sections, even in privileged (software has no RTOS and will always be in privileged mode).

As code will be running in privileged mode, I use `MPU_CTRL_PRIVDEFENA_Msk` flag, and wish to only overwrite access for my two regions.

I have checked the alignment requirements of those sections:

- Region 0 (in FLASH) @ `0x0001d400` (1k aligned)
- Region 1 (in SRAM)  @ `0x20000000` (1k aligned)

Find below my code to configure the MPU:

```
__disable_irq();

//
// Region0
//
__DSB();
__ISB();
MPU->RNR = 0;
MPU->RBAR = (0x0001d400 << MPU_RBAR_ADDR_Pos);
// 1k size - log2(1k) = 10
MPU->RASR  = ((10 - 1) << MPU_RASR_SIZE_Pos); 
// Normal; Not shareable; Cacheable; Inner Write back; no write allocate
MPU->RASR |= ((0x4 << MPU_RASR_TEX_Pos) | (1 << MPU_RASR_C_Pos) | (1 << MPU_RASR_B_Pos)); 
// No priviledged or unpriviledge access
MPU->RASR |= (0UL << MPU_RASR_AP_Pos);
// Enable
MPU->RASR |= 1UL;

//
// Section 1
//
__DSB();
__ISB();
MPU->RNR = 1;
MPU->RBAR = (0x20000000 << MPU_RBAR_ADDR_Pos);
// 1k size - log2(1k) = 10
MPU->RASR  = ((10 - 1) << MPU_RASR_SIZE_Pos); 
// Normal; Not shareable; Cacheable; Inner Write back; no write allocate
MPU->RASR |= ((0x4 << MPU_RASR_TEX_Pos) | (1 << MPU_RASR_C_Pos) | (1 << MPU_RASR_B_Pos)); 
// Read-Only Priviledged or unpriviledge access
MPU->RASR |= (6UL << MPU_RASR_AP_Pos);
// Enable
MPU->RASR |= 1UL;

// Enable MPU
MPU->CTRL = MPU_CTRL_ENABLE_Msk | MPU_CTRL_HFNMIENA_Msk | MPU_CTRL_PRIVDEFENA_Msk;
// Enable MemFault handler
SCB->SHCSR |= SCB_SHCSR_MEMFAULTENA_Msk;
__DSB();
__ISB();
__enable_irq();
```

It appears the configuration is ignored and it never generates a fault when accessing the configured region.

I have read the ARM documentation many times and cannot see what is wrong...

- Is there a mistake in my code?
- Is the cache/memory configuration wrong for SAMD51?
- Is what I want to do not achievable by staying in privileged mode?

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are some clear problems in your code. 
Please refer this for bit fields: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0337e/BIHHGADD.html

From the start:
1: Why are you shifting the base address here

```
MPU->RBAR = (0x0001d400 << MPU_RBAR_ADDR_Pos);
```

it needs to be like this. Refer for bit fields of this register.

```
MPU->RBAR = (0x0001d400);
```

2: This line has no effect. As this field has been already set to zero while setting the size and it is also incorrect. To clear the bit we use & operation not |.

```
MPU->RASR |= (0UL << MPU_RASR_AP_Pos);
```

3: For the testing purpose try with caches off. i-e tex=1, b=0, c=0, s=0. Also set instruction fetches bit XN to disable instruction fetches access.

Comment: 1. I used this https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0403/eb/DDI0403E_B_armv7m_arm.pdf#G15.4976374 as reference and misunderstood RBAR configuration. Thanks, that was obviouly the problem... shifting would truncate the address.
2. Although it has no effect, it is not a problem since RASR is affected two line above, then ored. Anyway...
3. Indeed, setting XN is safer in my case.